# Swipe Menu in Android

Tags: android

I know this might be a duplicate question but i am a beginner at android development so i am not even sure what i am searching for exactly but what i am trying to implement is a menu in which a person swipes to move to second item in menu.. i know about listview but what i want to implement is that when the user swipes to left or right it sees a new menu item. So it shouldnt be scrolling but a switch on swipping. I am not sure if am clear on this but i know one way of doing this is by creating an activity for each menu item but i think thats a noob step so can i anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a ViewPager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: thanks a lot man!!! that was what i was looking for!! i mean its closest to what i was looking for.. thanks a ton :)